# How to convert nvarchar to datetime if null values are present in the column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find the difference between the `move_in_date(datetime,null)` and `move_out_date(nvarchar(255),null)`, but I am getting the error

> "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

I tried converting the move_out date from nvarchar to datetime by using `convert(datetime,move_out_date,121) as Move_out_date` and `cast(move_out_date as datetime)as Move_out_date`, but I am getting the error

> "The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value"

Below is the data:

```
move_in_date             move_out_date
2015-02-12 00:00:00.000  30-04-2016
2015-06-05 00:00:00.000  NULL
2015-10-28 00:00:00.000  28-11-2016
2015-04-26 00:00:00.000  NULL
2015-05-15 00:00:00.000  27-12-2015
```

How can I find the difference between these two columns?

Comment: The correct answer is store dates as dates, not as strings.

Comment: Please show the query you are using.

Comment: `dd-mm-yyyy` is [style 105, not 121](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles), so you would need `CONVERT(DATETIME, move_out_date, 105 )`, or, to avoid errors, you can use [`TRY_CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead to avoid any errors. Or better still, store data using the correct data type: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your case is the style that you try to convert to.

The following query should work fine:

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT( DATETIME, '30-04-2016', 103) AS YourDate
```

For more styles, see this: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp